# Install Cometchat Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

So I'm new with laravel and I wanted to install cometchat into my app (I bought their basic package for $50).
I noticed that they had a bunch of supported MVCs except for Laravel, so I though it wouldn't be that hard to install it myself. It's been 3 days and I'm not giving up yet!

I'm assuming I have to extract the whole cometchat file into the /public folder in laravel but I can't get access /public/install.php

Has anyone ever tried to do this? If so, any help?

Thank you all! :)

Comment: You won't be able to access any url unless it's in your route file, probably why you can't get to install.php. Maybe this could help? http://www.cometchat.com/documentation/installing-cometchat/custom-coded-site/php-site/

Comment: You must upload the whole "cometchat" folder to the "public" folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you get it to work.

Download cometchat as a "custom coded site" (This will be under Download page) and extract it to /public/cometchat (If you don't have a cometchat folder in your public folder, make one).

Configure your integration.php with the right DB credentials and now you can access your install.php via http://localhost/public/cometchat/install.php

If you don't want the public folder to be shown in the url, create a .htaccess file and place it in the root directory of your progect

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

If you do have the .htaccess setup like above, access http://localhost/cometchat/install.php

One the installation is completed, remove the install.php file and you're done :)
Make sure you access localhost/cometchat/admin/ to change your admin credentials!